# PHP else if? Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a content type 'Article'

When creating a new article, I have the option to display 1 of 3 available fields. They are;

- Quote ['field_quote']
- External URL (Video/Audio) ['field_media']
- Image ['field_portfolio_image']

I am getting a bit stuck on how to write the correct syntax. Here is what I have so far.

```
    <?php if (isset($content['field_quote'])):?>
        <div class="quote-post">
           <blockquote>
           <?php print render($content['field_quote']);?>
           </blockquote>
        </div>  
          <?php elseif (isset($content['field_media'])):?>
            <?php print render($content['field_media']);?>
          <?php else: ?>
          <?php print render($content['field_portfolio_image']);?> 
 <?php endif;?>
```

The fields 'Quote' & 'Media' render, Portfolio Images will not.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($content)` and seeing what's in the array? maybe the quote/media options are never **UN**set, so the "else" clause never gets a chance to kick in.

Answer (score 1):

Because if condition is satisfied in some if - it will never execute else statement.
Example:

```
if (1==1) {
  // execute
}
elseif(2==2) {
  // execute
}
else {
  // NO execution
}
```

Do a separete if condition for each field.

Comment: Thank you I have fixed this issue now.